# Why can't I view my Thunderbird e-mails due to a lock file?

Tags: linux, email, unix, thunderbird

I'm not able to view my inbox mails, I'm using Thunderbird.

I have checked the `/var/mail` directory. There I saw the lock file: `/var/mail/$LOGINNAME.lock`

I have removed the lock file and restarted the Thunderbird, again the lock file is created.

I have changed the file group as mail from users. After that also the lock file is created.

I have restarted the machine. After re-booted the machine the file group has changes to users.

```
-rw------- 1 sugumar        users   1.4G 2011-09-30 20:14 sugumar
-rw------- 1 sugumar        mail     10 2011-09-30 20:30 sugumar.lock
```

I'm not able to stop the lock file creations. I'm not able to access my inbox.

What is the problem? How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The lock file is in place because of Thunderbird.  It exists as a way for the OS to know that a process is using the `/var/mail/sugumar` file and that process may update the file so it would be unsafe for any other process to modify/read the file until the lock file is gone.

The problem may be that the file `/var/mail/sugumar` is so large that Thunderbird crashes trying to index all of the emails.  1.4G is pretty large for an email file!

Try using `[ 09:00 jon@host ~ ]$ mail` and clearing out some of the unwanted emails, or make a backup of that file `[ 09:00 jon@host ~ ]$ gzip -v9 /var/mail/sugumar`, then `[ 09:00 jon@host ~ ]$ touch /var/mail/sugumar` to create an empty file.

Then if you ever want to go back to those old emails, just `gunzip` the `/var/mail/sugumar.gz` file.

Comment: Thanks...  I have used 3rd point Now I'm able to access the new mails.  How to restore the old mail into my Inbox ?

Comment: do `touch /var/mail/sugumar`, then open Thunderbird again and any new emails from then on should work.